# pointerdown event in chrome makes all further events only accosiated with the current browser window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

i have an application that runs two on two browser windows (in two screens) and node webkit helps me mange them both and let them have shared memory.

in the appication i have the ability to drag elements from one scren to the other (between the browsers). at first my idea was to listen to **pointerdown** event and when it triggers in its callback to start listening to **pointermove** and **pointerup** on the document of both windows. the was when i realized that chrome has some intresting behaviour when initiating a **pointerdown**.

from what it seems, after the **pointerdown** all the further events are happening only in the current browser, even when the pointer leaves its boundaries. for example the **pointermove** event will have negative clientX values when the pointer exists the screen from the left side, or it'll be way higher than the screen width when leaving the screen from the right.

i also tested some other events with regular chrome tabs, and with

```
monitorEvents(document, EVENT_NAME)
```

and the results where the same - without doing a pointer down both browsers where catching pointermove, pointerup and pointerenter events, but when doing a pointer down event on one of the windows it stopped getting all the poreviously mentioned events on the other window until a **pointerup** occured.

i even tried to cheat chrome by doing something like

```
let pointerDownCallback= (event) => {
    curerntScreenDocument.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerup'));

    firstScreenDocument.on('pointerup', pointerUpcallback);
    secondScreenDocument.on('pointerup', pointerUpcallback);

    firstScreenDocument.on('pointermove', pointerMoveCallback);
    secondScreenDocument.on('pointermove', pointerMoveCallback);
}

element.on('pointerdown', pointerDownCallback);
```

chrome got the **pointerup** event but it didnt stop the **pointerdown** behaviour.

i still have found a way to disable this kind of behaviour and i tried lots of things - playing with blur and focus and similar things.

for now what im doing is modifying the event that triggers in one screen to match the positions of the other screen and triggering a service that does the pointerup callback action in the correct screen.

```
let pointerUpcallback = (event) => {
// im getting the screen by using clienX and clientY of the event and by knowing the sizes of each screen;
let screen = getEventScreen(event) 

if(screen !== pointerDownOriginScreen) {
    // modify the event's positionb to match the correct screen
    event.screenX = ....
    event.screenY = ....
}

// get the service that will handle the pointerUp in the correct screen
let service = getServiceForScreen(screen)
service.handlePointerUp(screen);
```

}

i have a similar thing for the pointermove, also most of my oither actions are based on the positions that i get on the event and the correct screen that i know the event should happen in it.

this is a pretty dirrty wasy to handle this problem. so my question is - is there a way to handle this issue in a more elegant and natural way?

what im trying to achieve is making it possible to drag one element to different position including another chrome window (thats of course part of my application). to do that i implemented a custom drag behaviour in my system. the idea of this drag is to minimize the element that im starting to drag, and replace it with a smaller element that represents its heading (similar to the heading of a regular chrome tab, but without seeing the content of the tab). that heading should follow the mouse cursor (even when im switching screens) and when im releasing the drag the element should maximise to its original size and content.

i added a **pointerdown** event handler to the element that minimizes it, saves its content and adds **move** and **up** event listeners on the document of both the chrome windows.

the idea was that the heading will follow the cursor via the **pointermove**, evenwhen it moves to the other screen because now the one who will fire the event is the document of the other chrome window. same idea was for the **pointerup** events, so when the drag will end, i'll know in which screen it happened because he will fire the **pointerup** event.

but that isnt the case because chrome doesnt allow events to fire in another window once you have initiated a **pointerdown** event on your window. all the following events will only trigger for the origin window of the **pointerdown** event.

you can simulate that behaviour by opening 2 chrome windows and in the devtolls's console to write in both of the windows.

```
monitorEvents(documents, 'pointermove')
```

now when you'll move the cursor from one window to another, there will be **pointermove** events firing in each window's console. but when you'll click on one window and hold the pointer down and stat moving it around (over the other window too), you'll notice that the **pointermove** events fire only for the **pointerdown** event origin window. that is also the case for other events as well.

Comment: I am not an Expert of the PointerEvents API, and while your description got my curiosity, at the end, I kind of lost your exact use case and now wonder if I actually have to learn more about it to be able to tell you if what you experienced is indeed to be expected or some quirks of Chrome's implementation, or if you simply gone a long, complicated and still experimental path for a problem that has already a well defined solution. So to express it better, could try to add a little more emphasize on what you are trying to achieve rather than the weird behavior you found while trying to do it?

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah sorry it's a bit confusing to explain. Basically, we want to be able to drag elements through different chrome windows. We have a node server that opens multiple windows for us and let's us pass data between them. Does this make it more clear? Thanks.

Comment: And why can't you use the drag Events? They will allow you to do exactly this with even no need for backend sync.

Comment: @Kaiido We're also trying that but we just wanted to see if anyone has some better solutions. Not sure if I explained well enough. We don't just want normal drag and drop functionality. We're trying to simulate windows inside of chrome. Our application has many forms that should be movable between chrome windows. One of our objectives is to have the form updating/changing while we're in drag and then normal drag events don't work because on drag it just makes an image of the element. We're trying to create chrome windows and tabs but inside of the chrome document if that makes any sense.

Comment: Well you can very well pass html or any other data format through the [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) attached to your drag events.